# How to save kext configuration between sessions

Tags: macos, configuration, driver, kernel-extension

I am writing an OS X audio driver which will do some audio filtering. The driver kext is loaded on device connection and unloaded when device is unplugged. Driver configuration parameters are delivered via userspace application and can be changed during the device session.

If the helper app is closed then the driver will use the last received parameters (or fallback to default). However, instead of using default configuration every time the device is plugged in, it would be nice if the driver would load and store its configuration on kext load/unload respectively.

If I'm not mistaken, [Windows uses registry for this type of thing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565537(v=vs.85).aspx). I found [this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-kernel/2003/Dec/msg00052.html) message dating from year 2003, in which this sort of behavior is discouraged, and the only way to do it is to introduce a daemon which will launch on boot and will look after the kext.

Is there another (maybe easier) way to do the same thing 13 years later?

Comment: The recommendation still stands. Trying to save audio configuration from kernel space seems especially unnecessary considering Core Audio is all userspace and only legacy audio drivers are implemented in the kernel these days.

Comment: @pmdj Hi, thanks for your comment! I'm using [SampleUSBAudioPlugin](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/SampleUSBAudioPlugin/Introduction/Intro.html) example as a guide and it makes use of Kernel framework. Thus I concluded that I'm in kernel space and can't save or load from files. Maybe there's something obvious that I'm missing which will allow me to save the configuration of this plugin?

Comment: SampleUSBAudioPlugin is for USB audio devices which can be driven by Apple's USB audio driver but require some customisations. If you're trying to create a (virtual) audio driver from scratch, you want to look at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/AudioDriverExamples/Introduction/Intro.html. For virtual devices, the NullAudio example in this package is probably the best guide. (You can glean some details from the SimpleAudioDriver example which is unfortunately anything but simple.)